# Cloud Firestore web interface suddenly has become slow, even unresponsive

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Out of the blue, about 2 days ago, my Cloud Firestore web interface became agonizingly slow.

I am talking about the interface with URLs like [https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/my-company/firestore/data/~2Fmy-collection-name~2Fmy-document-ID](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/my-company/firestore/data/%7E2Fmy-collection-name%7E2Fmy-document-ID)

If I try to explore a document, for example to drill down its hierarchy, the web page either does not respond at all, or it takes forever (many 10s of seconds).

I now frequently get a browser warning dialog come up that says "Page Unresponsive": [image: This is a screenshot that I recently took]

To my knowledge, I have made no recent changes to my computer (e.g. browser settings).

I have tried to switch from Brave (my primary browser) to Chrome (only use for problematic websites), no joy.

I have tried turning my VPN on and off, no joy.

I even deleted my complete browser data (e.g. caches, history, etc) from all time in both Brave and Chrome, no joy.

It gets more frustrating: none of my coworkers seem to have this issue, only me.

Anyone, especially Google engineers, have any idea what is going on?

Comment: If you're having problems with the Firebase console, you should reach out to [Firebase support](https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support) directly.  Stack Overflow is for questions about programming.

Comment: *firebaser here* That sounds add indeed. As Doug also commented, can you file an issue with our support team. I know there was a change to the Firestore console earlier this week, and our support team is usually the best way to track if more people were affected - and escalate to the engineers if so.

Comment: If you file a ticket with support, tell them to escalate to me - so that I can route it to the right engineering team. Or send me the case number in Twitter DMs and I can pick it up from there too.

Comment: Does your document have a lot of data? I notice that when a doc is nearly full, particularly when it updates a lot, it can be difficult to load.

Comment: Guys: thanks for the suggestions to reach out to Firebase support directly, I will do so next.  To answer your question, @Nick, my documents could be viewed a dict of dicts (i.e. 2 hierarchical levels), and some of the dicts have 100s of entries.  So, maybe medium sized data and complexity?  But certainly nothing extraordinary.  I am sure that other Firestore users are way more extreme than me.  Also, I used to not have these problems, they just popped up out of the blue this week.

Comment: Reaching out to Google support was the right recommendation here.  It turns out that the Firestore team was doing some A/B testing, and whatever changes they did negatively impacted me.  My Firestore web interface is now back to normal speed.

Comment: Thanks @HaroldFinch for the update... I confirm I had the exact same symptoms at the exact same time... Now all is back to normal... Good to know it was A/B testing from Google team... Even after the potential "roll back", I still needed to "reload" web page to get rid of issue